# Template argument not matched in variadic tuple invoke function

Tags: templates, c++17, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction, generic-lambda

Why can the compiler not match the template parameter `F` in the `invoke()` Function.
Is there anywhere a non-deduced context I am not aware of??
And how can it be fixed?

[Live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kPZx3MoDWwN4Bq8l)

```cpp
// Invoke Function with all tuple arguments.
template<typename F, size_t... Is, typename Tuple>
auto invoke(F&& f, std::index_sequence<Is...>, Tuple&& t)
{
    return f(std::get<Is>(t)...);
}

template<typename F, typename Tuple>
auto invoke(F&& f, Tuple&& t)
{
    constexpr std::size_t uiLength = std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>;
    return invoke(std::forward<F>(f),
                  std::make_index_sequence<uiLength>{},
                  std::forward<Tuple>(t));
}

template<typename T>
struct A{
   using D = int;
};
template<typename... T>
auto make(T&...){
    return std::make_tuple(A<T>{}...);
}

int main()
{
  invoke([](auto&, auto&){}, std::make_tuple(A<int>{}, A<double>{})); // works
  //auto a = invoke(make, std::make_tuple(A<int>{}, A<double>{})); // does not compile, but why??
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anywhere a non-deduced context I am not aware of?? And how can it be fixed?

The problem is that you can't pass the **name** of a template function as argument of a function

```
template<typename... T>
auto make(T&...){
    return std::make_tuple(A<T>{}...);
}

// ...

auto a = invoke(make, std::make_tuple(A<int>{}, A<double>{}));
```

Try rewriting `make()` as a generic (and variadic) lambda (that is an object so you can pass it as argument to a function)

```
auto a = invoke([](auto & ... rData){ return std::make_tuple(A<decltype(rData)>{}...);},
                std::make_tuple(A<int>{}, A<double>{}));
```

Off Topic suggestion: rename `invoke()` with a different name (`myInvoke()`, by example) to reduce the risk of a name collision with `std::invoke()`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to define the function as a static lambda:

```cpp
static const auto makeDataHandles = [](auto&... t) {
    return std::make_tuple(A<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(t)>>{}...);
}
```